# Why is HTML a text file?

Tags: html

I am a beginner programmer and I'm starting the adventure with html. While learning one of the tutorials I came across a question. Why HTML is a text file. I have already searched all google but I found nothing. So I wanted to ask for help in providing a possible source for solving my problem. I will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: Files are just a sequence of bytes. How you interpret them is up to you.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but if your html is a text file you can simply change the extension to .html and your html will be a html file.

Comment: check this `html` website , it will answer you question https://html.com/#HTML_for_Absolute_Beginners

Comment: @NTR No! That depends upon file viewer program. If you written HTML inside file that have extension `.java`,  How to run | execute??? You will be only able to read or write....

Answer (score 0):

HTML was designed as a Hyper Text Markup Language. In the beginning it was used to tag text, paragraphs and headings. When it was designed it was used to create static web pages not the dynamic web we have today.

HTML is a text based format because it was easer for humans to work with.

There are more about the background on wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML